# Bitcoin core full node won't start on mac reboot!

Tags: full-node, mac

I had been running bitcoin core qt for a few months fine and then on rebooting my mac and opening the application the following prompt popped up

> Error: Cannot parse configuration file: specified data directory ""/Users/*username*/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/"" does not exist..

I'm a long way from being technically competent but I'm 99% sure the data directory does exist.

Any advice on what else this could be? or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: this error pops up if the mentioned directory is not found... so please dbl check if it exists... otherwise startup bitcoin-qt with --resetguisettings (`/Applications/Bitcoin-Qt.app/Contents/MacOS/Bitcoin-Qt --resetguisettings`).

Answer (score 1):

1. Place bitcoin core in the application folder
2. Start terminal
3. Paste

```
/Applications/Bitcoin-Qt.app/Contents/MacOS/Bitcoin-Qt --resetguisettings
```

4. Hit enter